# Adding 'a' or 'an' to a randomly generated string

Tags: ruby, character

How do I add 'a' or 'an' to a randomly generated string?

The random generator is `post[rand(post.length)]`.

How do I add 'a' or 'an' to the above result automatically when the post is starting with either a vowel or a consonant?

Comment: Check to see if it starts with /[aeiou]/ and tack on an "n" to the default "a" prefix? What have you tried so far?

Comment: wat i did was the randomly generate a 'post' from and array, dis works fine.

Comment: the other part is the add 'a' or 'an' to the post if the post genearted randomly started wit  a consonant or vowel

Comment: Your English is not excellent, so you may want to either use a third-party library, or get a colleague who knows English to check the rules you implement. If the former, you may want to look at https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/random_data_generation

Comment: Is this homework?  People will try to get you on track if it is.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm, what i was trying to explain is that, i've been able to randomly generate a string from an array, the problem i'm having is adding 'a' or 'an' to the string generated if the string starts with either a consonant or a vowel. though i'm quite new on ruby

Comment: What about 'an hour', 'an honourable gentleman', 'an heir to the throne', 'a unicorn', 'a user', 'a eulogy'?

Comment: @d11wtq, those will all fall under consonants, what i really i just a statement that ties the correct identifier 'a' or 'an' to each randomly generated string from an array

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_articles#Discrimination_between_a_and_an

Comment: @badadayo, so would you be happy with 'an user' and 'an unicorn', 'an one-legged pirate' etc... these are entirely incorrect.

Comment: the correct syntax, would just do for now, bcos of the strings available in the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting.
It seems to me that the algorithm here must look at the phonetic pronunciation of the beginning of the word that follows 'a' or 'an.'  Just looking at consonants and vowels will not be enough.  For example, here are some obvious choices and some exceptions to consider:

a one time thing
a unit of measure
a heavy concept
a high opinion
an egg to beat
an historic moment
an honest man
an owner of things
an eye for an eye

I suppose the answer to the OP will result from answering, "Is there an algorithm for describing the phonetic pronunciation of a word?"  If the word to follow begins with a vowel *sound*, then use 'an'  Otherwise, use 'a'

I wonder if this would help: http://creativyst.com/Doc/Articles/SoundEx1/SoundEx1.htm

Answer (score 0):

I understand *when the post is starting with vowel or a consonant* as: _If it start with a letter (no number or special sign).

This should modify your string:

```
  (randomstring << 'a') if randomstring =~ /\A\w/i
```

Or with a little testexample:

```
%w{
  ebbbbb
  debbbbb
  .debbbbb
}.each{|randomstring|
  (randomstring << 'a') if randomstring =~ /\A\w/i
  p randomstring 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if string contains your randomly generated string, then new_string will contain an output string with the word 'a' or 'an' in front of it:

```
new_string = (string=~/^[aeiou]/i ? 'an ' : 'a ') + string
```

This method does not take into account the case of the initial value on the input string, and try to substitute appropriately.  This is only an issue if you have to deal with the beginnings of sentences.

In the even that you do need to deal with the beginnings of sentences, I would recommend that you keep it simple and take the straight-forward method of checking to see if the first letter is a capital, and then building the new_string a little differently in each case: for a lowercase value, do like above, but for an uppercase value, you should downcase the first letter of the input string, and upcase the A in the ternary conditional.

Lastly, note that my example code isn't safe: it assumes that string is already a string object, and not something else (like nil).  How you handle bad input is dependent on what you are doing, but a .to_s on each call to string would at least keep it from crashing.

Comment: the problem is that, if i use the above command, the random generator attaches a new string to '+ string', this means that the output will be regex result + a newly random number

Comment: Won't work.  This approach will be grammatically incorrect for "a one time thing" and "a unit of measure", just to name a couple of examples.

Comment: the command i used was this:                                       def generate_identifier(ancient)
      if(ancient=~/^[aeiou]/)
      return "an"
      else
      return "a"
      end